# Convert boost::bind object to function pointer - implementing message map

Tags: c++, winapi, boost, signals

I'm thinking of creating a Window class library that uses Win32 API and C++ standard libraries
And I'd like to add signal/slot functionality that handles window messages.

```
using namespace std;
using namespace boost::signals2;
typedef signal<void (Window*, EventArgs*)> WndEvent; 

class EventArgs { public: HWND hWnd; WPARAM wParam; LPARAM lParam; };

class Window {
    protected: unordered_map<UINT, WndMsg*> msgMap;
    public: void addMsgHandler(UINT msg, void (*handler)(Window*, EventArgs*)) {
        auto iter=msgMap.find(msg);
        if(iter==msgMap.end()) {
            WndEvent* newEvent = new WndEvent();
            newEvent->connect(handler);
            msgMap.insert(make_pair(msg, newEvent));
        }
        else iter->second->connect(handler);
    }

    private: LRESULT wndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lparam) {
        for(auto iter=msgMap.begin(); iter!=msgMap.end(); iter++)
            iter->second->();
    }
};
```

In using that library:

```
class Form : public Window {
    void initialize() {// add here pair of 'message' and 'corresponding handler'
        addMsgHandler(WM_LBUTTONUP, boost::bind(&Form::onLButtonUp, this, _1, _2));
        ...
    }
    void onLButtonUp(Window* sender, EventArgs* e) { // event handler
        wchar_t buf[1000]; 
        wsprintf(buf, L"(%d, %d) clicked", GET_X_LPARAM(e->lParam), GET_Y_LPARAM(e->lParam));
        MessageBox(0, buf, L"", MB_OK);
    }
}
```

Here the problem is onLButtonUp's signature doesn't match since it's a class member function.
So I tried to use boost::bind and I got compile error like this:

```
 Window::addMsgHandler': cannot convert parameter 2 'boost::_bi::bind_t<R,F,L>' to 'void (__cdecl *)(Window *,EventArgs *)'
```

which means I have to change (from simple function pointer to boost function object?) the signature of addMsgHandler() but

I cannot determine the data type (with very long template parameters) to be passed.

The compile error message says

```
R=void,            
F=boost::_mfi::mf2<void,Form,Window *,EventArgs *>,1>                           
L=boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<Form*>,boost::arg<1>,boost::arg<2>>
```

Furthermore, since many other classes will be derived from class Window, I cannot know the template type when I define class *Window*.

Is there a proper way to pass boost.bind object as function parameter?

Comment: I'm not trying to store function pointers but signals. Can boost.function store signals?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not getting you point but...Then I should change the type of 'msgMap' from map to multimap, add functors to that multimap, and every time a message (WM_'s) is given  re-connect() all handlers to corresponding boost::signal, and trigger the signal? Isn't this weird? I think connect() should be called once for each handler.

Comment: The scenario I first thought was like this: store connect()'ed signals in map<UINT, signal>, not the functors themselves

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the intent of your code. :/ Now, a `signal` can connect any callable entity like a `boost::function`, so just make `addMsgHandler` a template that accepts anything as the handler and pass that to `connect`: `template<class F> void addMsgHandler(UINT msg, F handler){ ... newEvent->connect(handler); ... }`

Comment: Now for a seperate problem: Why do you store pointers in your map? This is only begging for trouble. Please store a `shared_ptr` if the intent is shared ownership (which doesn't seem to be the case), or simply `unique_ptr` if you have access to C++11.

Comment: Just because I'm new to STL/boost and I just wanted it look simple. I guess unique_ptr will work but I doubt it's fully implemented in VS2010.

Comment: Nope, VS 2010 (rather, VC++10) (mostly) correctly implements `unique_ptr`, so go and use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define it like this:

```
void addMsgHandler(UINT msg, const function<void(Window* , EventArgs*)>& slot);
```

Or even like this:

```
void addMsgHandler(UINT msg, const WndEvent::slot_type &slot);
```

Now, when calling this function, `slot` parameter should be a "callable" accepting 2 arguments of types `Window *` and `EventArgs *`, and you can create such a slot using `mem_fn`, `boost::bind`, `std::bind`, or just passing an appropriate raw function ptr.

Comment: Thanks. Implemented the first one and the app's working fine, even for the derived class Form. Now I can use addMsgHandler like this: addMsgHandler(WM_LBUTTONUP, bind(&Form::onLButtonUp, this, _1, _2));

Comment: @Jeffrey Goines ok, great. But in my opinion, the 2nd form is better, as it makes your intent more clear. And if you change WndEvent signature, `addMsgHandler` doesn't require changes.